# Return the number of not chosen items in a list

Tags: list, jsom, choice-field

I have a list with two choices:

```
"<Field Type='Choice' Name='Result' Format='RadioButtons'> "
                         + "<Default> </Default>"
                         + "<CHOICES>"
                         + "    <CHOICE>OK</CHOICE>"
                         + "    <CHOICE>NON OK</CHOICE>"
                         + "</CHOICES>"
                         + "</Field>";
```

By default, when no choice is selected, the list shows a "blank" value,
and it's ok for me.

Now, I know how to write in JSOM the CAML query to get the number items with a choice value, 
for example this to get the number of "OK" values:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Eq>' +
        '<FieldRef Name=\'Result\'/><Value Type=\'Choice\'>OK</Value>' +
        '</Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

but how to get the number of "blank" items?

Of course I have tried with this but doesn't work:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Eq>' +
        '<FieldRef Name=\'Result\'/><Value Type=\'Choice\'></Value>' +
        '</Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in your query:

```
"<Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Result' /></IsNull></Where></Query>"
```

Comment: This query is "quite" right. I have tried it and returns the number of all items (6 in my case), while only 2 are "blanks".  maybe there is something like "IsEmpty"?

Comment: I am afraid, there is nothing as such "IsEmpty". you can get the query schema documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).

and IsNull element details, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/isnull-element-query).

Comment: does this answers your question?

Comment: No, At last I have done the "negative" query to find the Empty items (like `where not 'OK' AND not 'NON OK'`)